# C# PostgreSQL date format exception

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have format exception when i trying to add '9/30/2019 5:15:54 PM'(DD-MM-YYYY) to my database.
I'm already SET datestyle = 'ISO, DMY'. So now i can use it like:

```
INSERT INTO products(name, createdat) values ('test', '9/30/2019 5:15:54 PM')
```

I have the same SQL command in C# and PostgreSQL, but it works only in Postgre-pgAdmin(nice joke C#).

How can fix this error in C#?

Comment: what is the column `createdat` defined as? is it a text column? or a date/timestamp/something column? note: it should *probably* not be a text column, and if so: pass it *as a `DateTime`* via a parameter, and you should have a much easier time

Answer (score 0):

Well if you insert a valid Postgres timestamp literal, it should work everywhere:

```
INSERT INTO products (name, createdat)
VALUES
    ('test', '2019-09-30 17:15:54'::timestamp);
```

Perhaps the setting you configured were only valid from the session originating from pgAdmin, but not with the Postgres driver which C# is using.  In any case, the default Postgres timestamp literal is ISO compliant (your version is not), which is always a good thing.